# Disqus not showing

Tags: comments

I have been trying to set up Disqus commenting system on my website. For some reason it does not show on my website.

I have follow many YouTube tutorials, the module documentation and the documentation from Disqus, on how to implementing Disqus in my website and for some reason I still no able to see it.

I found some that have a solution in this [post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1159690#comment-5894238). By adding this piece of code.

```
   <?php
      print render($content['disqus']);
   ?>
```

And even with this I'm not able to show my disqus comments.

I enable the module and give permission to anonymous, authenticated and administrator to see Disqus comments. The current location view is on the content.

Can someone help me troubleshoot this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to, don't add Disqus via templates. It depends on how you're implementing it and what tools you're using, but I suggest using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds).

1. In the Disqus settings under the Visibility tab (admin/config/services/disqus), enable the content types using Disqus and change the location to Block.
2. In Display Suite, add a new Block field (admin/structure/ds/fields/manage_block) and select the Disqus Comments block.
3. In your Default or Full display, add the block to the appropriate region.
4. Under Disqus permissions, add anonymous and authenticated users to View Disqus comments. (probably your specific issue)